# left align and right align of a table

Tags: xepersian

I used below code to create a table. The problem is, I want the first coloumn from right to be left aligned and first coloumn from left to be right aligned. Also I want the first row of all column to be right aligned. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Off-topic: Is there any reason for loading `mathrsfs` twice?

Comment: No. It was a mistake

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{r|c|l}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<column header>}` at first and last column header (from left :) ) ?

Comment: @Zarko what do you mean by last column header?

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{r|c|l}\hline\multicolumn{1}{c}{<1. column header>} & <2. column header> & \multicolumn{1}{c}{<3.column header>} \\ right aligned text   & centered text & left aligned text \\ ...` . I understand, that you like to have something like this (all is considered from left to right).

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that left is right and right is left in the columns specifier of the `tabular` environment. Starting the table with

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|r}
```

makes the rightmost column and the center column left-aligned and the leftmost column right-aligned. To change the alignment of single entries, enclose the headers that should be right-aligned in

```
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{...}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,oneside,phd]{report}‎
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % inserting images‎
%\usepackage{hyperref} % PDF links‎
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{setspace} % for switching between double/single space in document‎
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % package for changing Headings style‎
% ‎setting the margins of page‎
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{align}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\nn}{\nonumber}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\def\nn{\nonumber}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=1.6]{IranNastaliq.ttf}
\defpersianfont\nastaliqq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq.ttf}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\lhead{\thepage}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{XBZar.ttf}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{XBZar.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{بیبعدqسازی} \label{tab:my}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|r}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{‎‎‏کمیت }&\multicolumn{1}{r|}{ مقدار بی‌بعد‌نشده }& مقدار بی‌بعد ‌شده ‎\\‎
‎‏‏شعاع ویچک& ‎‎$‎r = 2 ‎\mu m‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{r}= ‎‎\frac{r}{l} ‎=1‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‎‏‏‏سرعت ذاتی باکتری& ‎‎$‎v_0‎ = 2 ‎‎\frac{\mu m}{s}‎‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{v}_0 = ‎‎\frac{v_0 l^2}{l D_‎\parallel‎} = 40‎‎$ ‎\\‎‎
‎‏‏گام زمانی شبیه سازی& ‎‎$‎‎\Delta ‎t‎ = 1 s‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$\overline{‎‎\Delta ‎t}= ‎‎\frac{D_‎\parallel ‎‎\Delta ‎t}{l^2} ‎=0.1‎$ ‎\\‎‎
‎‏‏‏ضریب پخش زاویه‌ای شناگر& ‎‎$D_‎r = \frac{3 k_{B}T \: ‎ln(\frac{‎l‎}{b})}{\pi \: ‎\eta \: l^3} = 0.3 ‎\frac{1}{s}‎$‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{D}_r = ‎‎\frac{D_r \times  l^2}{D} ‎=14‎$ ‎\\‎‎
‎‏‏ضریب پخش انتقالی شناگر& ‎‎$D_‎\parallel = ‎0.1 ‎‎\frac{\mu m^2}{s}‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{D_‎\parallel}= ‎‎\frac{D_‎\parallel}{D_‎\parallel} ‎=1‎$ ‎\\‎‎
‎‏‏ضریب پخش غذا& ‎‎$D_c = ‎\frac{k_B T}{6 \pi \eta r_0} = 20 ‎\frac{\mu m^2}{s}‎‎‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{D}_c= ‎‎\frac{D_c}{D} ‎=2000‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏ضریب کموتکسی زاویه‌ای& ‎‎$\chi_‎r = ?‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{\chi}_‎r‎=?‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏ضریب کموتکسی انتقالی& ‎‎$\chi_{t‎r} = ?‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{\chi}_{t‎r}= ?‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏چگالی شناگر‌ها& ‎‎$\rho_0 = ?‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{\rho}_0= l^2 ‎\times‎ \rho_0 ‎=?‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏فاصله‌ی سایت‌های شبکه& ‎‎$‎\Delta ‎l‎ = ?‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$\overline{‎\Delta ‎l}= ‎‎\frac{‎\Delta ‎l}{l} ‎=?‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏چگالی اولیه‌ی غذا& ‎‎$c_0 = ?‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{c}_0 = c_0 ‎\times‎‎ l^2 = ‎‎?‎$ ‎\\‎
‎‏‏نرخ مصرف غذا& ‎‎$‎K=?‎‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎& ‎‎‎$‎\bar{K}= ‎‎\frac{K l^2}{D_‎\parallel‎}=?‎‎$ ‎\\‎
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** From the comments it seems that all columns should be left-aligned and all headings right-aligned. Second try:

[image]

```
...
\caption{بیبعدqسازی} \label{tab:my}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{‎‎‏کمیت}
& \multicolumn{1}{r|}{ مقدار بی‌بعد‌نشده }
  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{ مقدار بی‌بعد ‌شده ‎}
\\‎
‎‏‏شعاع ویچک
& ‎‎$‎r = 2 ‎\mu m‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎
  & ‎‎‎$‎\bar{r}= ‎‎\frac{r}{l} ‎=1‎$ 
\\‎
...
```

**Edit 2:** To color rows, load the packages `xcolor` and `colortbl`, define the color for the first row using `\definecolor` or `\colorlet`, and then set the color in the table using the command `\rowcolor`. Side note: Consider to increase `\arraystretch` to make the table better readable, see below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\colorlet{headline}{blue!30} % define headline color in one place such that it can be changed easily for the whole document
\usepackage{xepersian}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=1.6]{IranNastaliq.ttf}
\defpersianfont\nastaliqq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq.ttf}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{XBZar.ttf}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{XBZar.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{بیبعدqسازی} \label{tab:my}
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
\rowcolor{headline}
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{‎‎‏کمیت}
  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{ مقدار بی‌بعد‌نشده }
    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{ مقدار بی‌بعد ‌شده ‎}
\\‎
  ‎‏‏شعاع ویچک
  & $r = 2 ‎\mu m‎$
    & $\bar{r}= ‎‎\frac{r}{l} ‎=1‎$
\\
  ‎‎‏‏‏سرعت ذاتی باکتری
  & $‎v_0‎ = 2 ‎‎\frac{\mu m}{s}‎‎$‎
    & ‎‎‎$‎\bar{v}_0 = ‎‎\frac{v_0 l^2}{l D_‎\parallel‎} = 40‎‎$
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but in your table, first left coloumn is not leftaligned.

Comment: @saranj Well, you wrote: "I want ... and first coloumn from left to be right aligned". So the first column from left is right aligned.

Comment: @saranj See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. It was a mistake by me. BTW, Is there any way to make the first row of table coloured?

Comment: @saranj See the second edit to my answer.

Comment: @gernot ahahhah. I have written the truth. Thank you for writing in Arabic :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I wish I could write in Arabic.